# Fix Fragment Injection vulnerability in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, security, xamarin.android

As you know Android Developers:

> Beginning March 1, 2017, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or updates where PreferenceActivity classes may be vulnerable to Fragment Injection

In the page https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188427 it gives some advices on how to fix this vulnerability **but what about the applications developed with Xamarin?**

I haven't been able to found any information on this. It says that my affected class is SettingActivity, which inherits from PreferenceActivity, and my class SettingActivity is this:

```
 [Activity(
    Label = "@string/ApplicationName",
    Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher",
    Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light",
    ParentActivity = typeof(MainActivity))]
[IntentFilter(
    new [] {Intent.ActionManageNetworkUsage},
    Categories= new [] {Intent.CategoryDefault}
)]
public class SettingsActivity : PreferenceActivity
{
    public static readonly string KeyWifiOnly = "pref_wifi_only";

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences);

        ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        PreferenceManager.SetDefaultValues(this, Resource.Xml.preferences, false);

        SetupNetworkPreferences();
    }

    private void SetupNetworkPreferences()
    {
        var prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        ListPreference list = FindPreference(
            AppSettings.PreferenceNetworkProvider) as ListPreference;

        list.SetEntries(
            Enum.GetNames(typeof(AppSettings.FtpHostNetwork)));

        list.SetEntryValues(Enum
            .GetValues(typeof(AppSettings.FtpHostNetwork))
            .Cast<int>()
            .Select(x => x.ToString())
            .ToArray());
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        var tracker = (Application as App).Tracker;
        tracker.Screen("PantallaPreferencias");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try set export to false `[Activity(
    Label = "@string/ApplicationName", Exported =false,
    Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher",
    Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light",
    ParentActivity = typeof(MainActivity))]
[IntentFilter(
    new [] {Intent.ActionManageNetworkUsage},
    Categories= new [] {Intent.CategoryDefault}
)]`

Comment: Yes, this do the trick. Thanks a lot Mike. You just saved my job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mike Ma in the comments:

Adding the exported=false propierty worked just fine.

```
[Activity( Label = "@string/ApplicationName", Exported =false, Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light", ParentActivity = typeof(MainActivity))]
```